# Global array with custom objects is not keeping objects' state

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am creating a bucket list app and I need to be able to save each `BucketListGoal` from a `UITextField` in a `UITableViewCell`. Here is my relevant code below -

```
@interface BucketListGoalViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CreateGoalTableViewCellDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *goals;
@property NSInteger path;
@end



@implementation BucketListGoalViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.navigationItem.title = @"Goals";
self.count = 0;

self.goals = [[NSArray alloc] init];
[self createNewGoal];

self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;;
[self.tableView registerClass:[CreateGoalTableViewCell class]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CreateGoalTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleCoordinatesFromBucketList:)
                                             name:@"Coordinates"
                                           object:nil];


UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];



}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CreateGoalTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell.textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

cell.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.delegate = self;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.textField.delegate = self;
BucketListGoal *goal = [self.goals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
goal.tag = indexPath.row;

if (goal.address != nil) {
    [cell.locationButton setTitle:goal.address forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
goal.name = cell.detailTextLabel.text;

cell.textField.placeholder = @"Write the description of your goal here.";

cell.numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld)", (long)indexPath.row + 1];
return cell;
}

-(void)createNewGoal {

BucketListGoal *goal = [BucketListGoal new];
NSMutableArray *copy = [self.goals mutableCopy];

[copy addObject:goal];


self.goals = copy;

[self.tableView reloadData];


}


-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField{

NSMutableArray *copy = [self.goals mutableCopy];

BucketListGoal *goal = [self.goals objectAtIndex:textField.tag];


goal.name = textField.text;

[copy replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:goal];

self.goals = copy;

}
```

I create the goal from a bar button item at the top of the view. The issue is that `self.goals` is only keeping the `goal.name` of the latest item of the array. All the other previous items from the text fields continue being `nil`. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're doing `goal.name = cell.detailTextLabel.text` and I don't see anywhere where you set that text to something so it's always going to be nil.

Comment: Dan, I believe I'm setting it in `textFieldDidChange`. Every time text is changed in the UITextField that method runs.

Comment: You're setting `goal.name` there but you just override it again with the nil text from `cell.detailTextLabel.text` the next time your table reloads.

Comment: Ah! That fixed it. Thank you!!